# BxSlider Carousel - Changing one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, bxslider

I am using BxSlider Carousel in my project. Here is the link from bxslider;

http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified

I am using the vertical one. What I want to adjust and achieve there is to change the slides one by one when clicking the Next - Prev buttons. It changes two of them or three of them according to our determination on how many of them we want to show at the same time. I hope I could express the problem well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see http://bxslider.com/options , Carousel section; moveSlides parameter.
It allows you to determine how many slides you want to move at once.

> moveSlides
>   The number of slides to move on transition. This value must be >= minSlides, and <= maxSlides. If zero (default), the number of fully-visible slides will be used.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  moveSlides: 1
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't see options part. It works very well.